# Open modal window this custom jsp on it in Liferay

Tags: jsp, modal-dialog, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I need to open a modal window after clicking a button, the content of that modal window has to be a custom jsp located in the portlet.

I've tried the following posts but anyone works for me.

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-62-aui-dialog-liferay-popup.html
https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/39768821

In all cases, the modal window open but with the page that load inside is the same page where the button is.

The route where my jsp be is:

```
webapp\custom_jsps\html\portlet\document_library\test.jsp
```

The portletURL is:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="simpleDialogExample" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString()%>">
   <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/portlet/document_library/test.jsp"/>
   <portlet:param name="message" value="Hello welcome"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

I've tried also the following param:

```
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/test.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="\test.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/custom_jsps/html/portlet/document_library/test.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="\custom_jsps\html\portlet\document_library\test.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/portlet/document_library/test.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/test.jsp"/>
```

Any help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to open hooked jsp in modal window from your custom portlet?

Comment: Yeah, Inside my Theme there are some liferay jsp that has been modified, the folder is called "customs-jsp" and there are referenced in liferay-hook.xml.
In one of those jsp's, i have to include a button to open in a pop-up another own jsp and make some funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a modal window with liferay. Customize to your taste

[Liferay modal](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-62-aui-dialog-liferay-popup.html)